# mouse_move_to DEPRECATED ruby selenium cucumber

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, rubymine, webautomation

I am new to Selenium and want to hover over Category button then click the Subcategory in provided drop down. I used 'mouse_move to' command before but now it says: WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Driver#mouse is deprecated. Use driver.action..perform instead. 
I tried this code changing 'mouse' to 'action' and 'click' to 'perform' but it doesn't work.

```
 element = $driver.find_element :xpath => "//span[@class = 'ls_2px' and text() = 'Accessories']"
  $driver.mouse.move_to element
 element = $driver.find_element :xpath => "(//div[@class = 'vt'][.//a[text() = 'View All']]//a[0])"
  element.click
 end
```

Do I need to add WebDriver::W3CActionBuilder to my env file? 
I have only this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'
$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
$dropdown = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select
```

Comment: Hi, Don't use SeleniumBinding Directly If you are to use Ruby Binding, Use WATIR which is a wrapper around selenium Ruby Binding. And Try it in WATIR, if you have any question after that, post the question using WATIR tag.

Comment: For Ruby I'd recommend using Capybara, which can be used with various drivers including selenium. It has much simpler methods for most web actions.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.action.move_to(element).perform` should work in this case for `Hover`.

Resource: [Class: Selenium::WebDriver::ActionBuilder - `move_to`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#move_to-instance_method)